# How to add a row within another row?

Tags: magento2, cms-block

I want to add a row within another row through admin panel blocks.
I'm trying to but it doesn't work so, is it even possible ?

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in some more details.

Comment: I'm trying to equip a theme inside magento
So now I'm in the implementing the page components CMS, so I have a div that is inside another div and I'm trying to implement that by adding two rows inside each other so I can solve it.